# Get destination url from a link

Tags: react-native, short-url, bitly

I have some links like this redirect urls as below

```
url(bit.ly/3qOnbQt)
```

As this is short url. It's destination url is google.com

So i want destination url in react native. So anybody can provide me a solution for a library that can provide me destination url.